# Including files from another catkin workspace

Tags: ros, catkin, include, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having difficulty setting the include paths that I need for a ros node I'm building.

I need to include some header files from a different catkin workspace in order to use some services from another custom node. The catkin workspace path of with the header files I need is '~/ptu47_wss' under this the path '/src/dp_ptu47_pan_tilt_stage/include/dp_ptu47_msgs' contains the include files I need.

The catkin workspace for the project I'm working on is called 'catkin_project' and is in my home directory the same as 'ptu47_wss'

How do I set up my CMakeLists.txt file so that these header files can be included in my project?

Thanks, Pete

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226928/including-files-from-another-catkin-workspace/) by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9529 on 2016-02-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-17**:
Could this be an [xy-problem](http://xyproblem.info/)? Workspace overlaying as mentioned by @joq would certainly work, but do you have any particular reason for not placing the `dp_ptu47_pan_tilt_stage` package in the same workspace as your other node?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-02-17**:
Good point. Overlays are not required if all your dependencies are together in your main workspace. (But technically, any dependencies on `/opt/ros/indigo/` are also a sort of overlay.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The feature you're looking for is called [overlaying a catkin workspace](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying#Chaining_catkin_workspaces).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2016-02-17**:
That's exactly it, thank you. now I've got another problem round the circle goes. . .